# python 33 pickle class instance in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, cpython

the following code

```
import pickle
class Member:
    global members
    try:
        with open('member dict.txt','rb') as f:
            members=pickle.load(f)
    except:
        members={}

    def __init__(self,name,info,new=True):
        if name in members and new:
            print('name is taken')
            self.name='Void'
            self.info={'Void':'Void'}
        else:
            self.info=info
            self.name=name
            members[name]=self
            if new:
                with open('member dict.txt','wb') as f:
                    pickle.dump(members,f)
    def __getstate__(self):
        return[self.name,self.info]
    def __setstate__(self,d):
        return Member(d[0],d[1],False)
```

then in idle (after prssing f5 in the first code) I type

`PJ=member('P',{})`

I close idle then reopen it and type

```
members
```

it returns `{}`

Comment: Why put `members` into the class definition *at all*?

Comment: i put it in as a way to see all of the instaces i want to creat a digital club higharchy

Comment: What is the exception in your try block? Use `except Exception as e:` and print out e.

Comment: @forivall there is none

Comment: Don't be daft, there is always an exception. Do what I said (store it in a variable and print it), so that I can help.

Comment: @forivall [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'member dict.txt'  sory i thought you ment the hole programe.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code myself, and the *second* time your program is run, the error is `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Member'`. You're trying to unpickle your class before it's properly been constructed. To extend on the first comment, putting `members` into the class definition *is* what's making your code fail. Move it below the class definition, and it will work.

```
class Member:
    def __init__(self, name, info, new=True):
        ...
    ...

try:
    with open('member dict.txt', 'rb') as f:
        members = pickle.load(f)
except Exception as e:
    members = {}
```

Comment: thank you so much.I never would have thought of that.I will vote up as soon as I can.